# How to remove the `get` and `set` from IntelliJ getter/setter generation

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, code-generation

Given I have a POJO like:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
}
```

How can I have IntelliJ generate getters and setters without the prefix `get` and `set`?

To get this:

```
public String name() {
    return this.name;
}

public void name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? to make sure the person who is to use them won't know what they are (supposed to be) doing?

Comment: The JavaBean spec states that the names are prefixed with `get/set` (as well as the optional `is` for primitive booleans). Are you really sure you want to start using your own convention instead of the one followed by all other Java programmers?

Comment: The attributes are basically public when you use this convention... Try to get used to the conventional way of using getters and setters, it makes for much better, more readable code.

Comment: @JochemKleine Not only that, it can affect libraries that expect objects to be JavaBeans. Using your own naming convention will result in those libraries to think your objects have no properties at all.

Comment: The correct answer has been given; however, I will definitely support what everyone else is saying, get/set is the Java convention and you probably should stick with it since it is what maintainers will expect. Also, if you ever hope to marshal/unmarshal to xml/json with JAXB you will need the get/set prefixes.

Comment: Hey people first of all thank you very much for your comments. The reason why I've made this questions is because I've been working with RoR for the last 3 years where this kind of conventions are the way to go. So did some research and I found this https://dzone.com/articles/upgrade-your-code-conventions-2

Comment: @EmilianoZilocchi best to go with the conventions of the platform you are currently using, rather than the one you were using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** the type of getter/setter you want goes against naming conventions, best practices and [specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1454519509_2a3b9625e83a03b868fdb1ba9241fb09#page=40) (see section 7 starting on page 40). Many libraries, such as those used for serialization or marshalling expect the `getFoo` and `setFoo` type getters and setters, and those libraries will not work as expected if you use the type of getters and setters that you want to generate.

That being said, it is possible to change the default getter/setter generation in IntelliJ.

As you may know, you can select **Code**|**Generate** from the IntelliJ menu bar, or use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> shortcut to bring up the Generate window. From there, you can select Getter, Setter, or Getter and Setter. When you select one of those options, a dialog will open to select a template and which fields to generate getters/setters for.

If you select the <kbd>...</kbd> next to the template dropdown, it will open a separate template management dialog.

I would recommend copying the IntelliJ Default template, using the copy icon, or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut, and giving your new template a different name, such as 'Variable Name Only'.

Then, you can modify the template to fit your needs.

Here is the IntelliJ Default getter template:

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  get##
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

You should be able to remove the boolean check altogether, since for your template, the method name won't depend on the type of the variable. The following template should give you the getter that you want:

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
##
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

And this should give you the desired setter:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void $StringUtil.decapitalize($StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

Comment: Is there any document to describe how to write the template? because I want to write more complex template for setter and getter, such as operation on String(substring, indexOf etc.) I have try some method, some method is work, but some doesn't work.

Comment: They are [velocity templates](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html).